# Why does the regexp global flag disable capturing groups?

Tags: javascript, regex

consider the following code:

```
let x='father';

let m=x.match(/fa(.?)(.?)er/g); // x == ["father"]

let m=x.match(/fa(.?)(.?)er/); // x == ["father", "t", "h"]
```

So with the 'g' global flags, the capturing groups do not match. Why does this happen ?

Comment: That's the way it is [*if you want to obtain capture groups and the global flag is set, you need to use `RegExp.exec()` instead.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Using_global_and_ignore_case_flags_with_match())

Comment: It was designed so ... If the regular expression includes the g flag, the method returns an Array containing all matched substrings rather than match objects. Captured groups are not returned. If there were no matches, the method returns null.

Comment: thx passion, if you post an answer I'll approve it

Comment: Please do a spell and grammar check on your post title. Also, please follow standard international English conventions, where the first word in a sentence is capitalized, and there is no space before the punctuation ending a sentence.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), please. It explains this quite clearly.